# React Native / Expo Font Variant ignored on iOS works on Web

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo

I've dug through stack / the general web and couldn't find anything on this.

I have a React Native / Web app built with Expo.

I have loaded a custom font via Expo Fonts as suggested.

```
let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({"MyFont": require("pathtomyfont"})
```

Font loads great and displays. Lovely.

However, our designers are using

```js
number case: lining,
number spacing: tabular,
```

I attempted to set this like so:

```js
style={{fontVariant: ["lining-nums", "tabular-nums"]}}
```

Typescript seems quite happy with this - and it works just fine on the web and on android. However iOS seems to completely ignore this.

Am I setting this incorrectly on iOS? Notice in the outputs below how the 0's are correct on android but not on iOS. The web renders like android.

ios:

[image]

android:

[image]